# Couldn't get the Virtual Machine list from Scaleset

Tags: java, azure

We were using azure-mgmt-compute-1.3.0.jar (Azure SDK) to discovery the VMscaleset from our account and inturn find the list of VMs under the VMSCaleset, We could able to get the VMscaleset but couldnt able to get the list of VMS under the scaleset, Is there is any changes done on this part.

Below is the Java Code we were trying.

```
ComputeManager compMgr = ComputeManager.authenticate(credentials, 'Subscritpion Number');
PagedList list = compMgr.virtualMachineScaleSets().list();
for (VirtualMachineScaleSet virtualMachineScaleSet : list)
{
System.out.println(virtualMachineScaleSet.name());

//Not working
PagedList pagedList = virtualMachineScaleSet.virtualMachines().list();
//Here size of pagedList is always 0

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> PagedList pagedList = virtualMachineScaleSet.virtualMachines().list();
>   //Here size of pagedList is always 0

Based on my test, your code should work. If you get that size of pagedList is 0, it means that there is no instance in the virtualMachineScaleSet. You could check it from Azure portal.

The following is my test code.

```
String client = "client Id";
String tenant = "tenant Id";
String key = "secret key";
String subscription = "subscription Id";
ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(client,
                tenant,
                key,
                AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
ComputeManager compMgr = ComputeManager.authenticate(credentials, subscription);
PagedList<VirtualMachineScaleSet> list = compMgr.virtualMachineScaleSets().list();
for (VirtualMachineScaleSet virtualMachineScaleSet : list)
{
   System.out.println(virtualMachineScaleSet.name());
   PagedList pagedList = virtualMachineScaleSet.virtualMachines().list();
   System.out.println(pagedList.size());
 }
```

**[image: Test Result]**